# looping through items using xPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath

I am tryng to loop through an xml doc and I am still getting the first element in the second iteration, not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help? Pretty new with Xpath

```
string file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/Locations.xml");

    Dictionary<string, Location> locationCollection = new Dictionary<string, Location>();

        XPathDocument xDocument = new XPathDocument(file);
        XPathNavigator xPathNavigator = xDocument.CreateNavigator();

        foreach (XPathNavigator node in xPathNavigator.Select("//locations/*"))
        {
            string value = node.SelectSingleNode("/locations/location/cell").Value;
        }



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<locations>
  <location>
    <locationName>Glendale</locationName>
    <street>3717 San Fernando Road</street>
    <city>Glendale</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zipcode>91204</zipcode>
    <generalManager>DJ Eldon</generalManager>
    <phone>(818) 552‐6246</phone>
    <tollFree>(888) 600‐6011</tollFree>
    <fax>(818) 552‐6248</fax>
    <cell>(347) 834‐2249</cell>
    <counterEmail>BUR@Eaglerider.com</counterEmail>
    <directEmail>DJ@Eaglerider.com</directEmail>
  </location>
  <location>
    <locationName>Chicago</locationName>
    <street>1301 S. Harlem Ave.</street>
    <city>Chicago</city>
    <state>IL</state>
    <zipcode>60402</zipcode>
    <generalManager>Dave Schnulle</generalManager>
    <phone>(708) 749‐1500</phone>
    <tollFree>(888) 966‐1500</tollFree>
    <fax>(818) 552‐6248</fax>
    <cell>(708) 749‐3800</cell>
    <counterEmail>ORD@Eaglerider.com</counterEmail>
    <directEmail>Dave@Eaglerider.com</directEmail>
  </location>  
</locations>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're effectively ignoring the value of `node` by using a leading slash to get back to the document root. Try this instead:

```
// This assumes that there are only location nodes under locations;
// You may want to use //locations/location instead
foreach (XPathNavigator node in xPathNavigator.Select("//locations/*"))
{
    string value = node.SelectSingleNode("cell").Value;
    // Use value
}
```

Having said that, is there any reason you're not doing it in a single XPath query?

```
// Name changed to avoid scrolling :)
foreach (XPathNavigator node in navigator.Select("//locations/location/cell"))
{
    string value = node.Value;
    // Use value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great... Yes, there is a reason I am not doing a single xpath because I will be adding multipule values to a collection.


Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
XPathNodeIterator ni = xPathNavigator.Select("//locations/*");
while (ni.MoveNext())
{
    string value = ni.Current.Value);
}
```

Just a quick blurt, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you should do:

```
string value = node.SelectSingleNode("./cell").Value;
```

When you do xPathNavigator.Select("//locations/*")), you're already inside /locations/location so you need to move just one element down the node, cell in your example.