# JDOM-XPath: Can't get the second value in a collection

Tags: expression, xpath, jdom

I'm pretty confused about this one.  Given the following xml:

```
<sch:eventList>
   <sch:event>
      <sch:eventName>Event One</sch:eventName>
      <sch:locationName>Location One</sch:locationName>
   </sch:event>
   <sch:event>
      <sch:eventName>Event Two</sch:eventName>
      <sch:locationName>Location Two</sch:locationName>
   </sch:event>
</sch:eventList>
```

When using JDOM using the following code:

```
  XPath eventNameExpression = XPath.newInstance("//sch:eventName");

  XPath eventLocationExpression = XPath.newInstance("//sch:eventLocation");

  XPath eventExpression = XPath.newInstance("//sch:event");

  List<Element> elements = eventExpression.selectNodes(requestElement);
  for(Element e: elements) {
      System.out.println(eventNameExpression.valueOf(e));
      System.out.println(eventLocationExpression.valueOf(e));
  }
```

The console shows this:

```
 Event One
 Location One
 Event One
 Location One
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use '//' it starts always searching at the root node. Use e.g. './sch:eventName' it is relative to the current node.

Comment: Sorry, I only just found the same issue has already been dealt with. Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945512/looping-through-items-using-xpath